# $\min_{\small X} \left\| X - Y\right\|_{2}^{2} + \left\| DX \right\|_{2}^{2}$

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Given that
$\quad  X, Y \in R^{N \times M}$
$\quad D \in R^{N \times N}$

Finding it difficult to proceed differentiation on these matrix equation.

The above form can be rewritten as follows
**Equivalent Form**

$\quad \min_{\small X} \left ( X-Y \right )\left ( X - Y \right )^{t} + \left ( DX \right )\left ( DX \right )^{t}$

**Proceeded Idea**

I proceeded with taking the equivalent form of objective function

$\quad f(X) = \left ( Y - X \right )\left ( Y - X \right )^{t} + \left ( DX \right )\left ( DX \right )^{t}$
$\quad f(X) = YY^{t} -YX^{t}- XY^{t} +XX^{t} + DXX^{t}D^{t}$
$\quad f(X) = YY^{t} -\left ( XY^{t} \right )^{t}- XY^{t} +XX^{t} + DXX^{t}D^{t}$

Differentiating the expression

$ = \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} X} \left ( XY^{t} \right )^{t} - \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} X} XY^{t} + \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} X} XX^{t} + \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} X} DXX^{t}D^{t}$

The expression has terms with three different forms

$\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} X} XY^{t}$
$\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} X} XX^{t}$
$\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} X} DXX^{t}D^{t}$

Is this approach a valid one? Am I missing core idea?
Im not sure how to approach these derivatives terms.

Comment: It's still unclear. What do you mean by minimising a matrix-valued function? Is the objective function the *trace* of $(X-Y)(X-Y)^t+\ldots$?

Comment: Yes, minimization is done on a matrix-valued function. Objective function remains the same. If you want, I can share the conference paper, where this is implemented. But it does not discuss about how to minimize the objective function.

Comment: @Senume No, the minimization is NOT done on matrix-*valued* functions, that doesn't make any sense.  You can only talk about minimizing a function if the values take place in something that has minimums (real numbers, integers, etc, but NOT $\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb C$).  Your reformulation is NOT correct unless $N=1$.  Ask yourself, what would the minimum of two vectors even mean? What is the minimum of (1,2) and (2,1)?  The question doesn't make sense, because there is not a total ordering on the set of vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from context that your norm is the Frobenius norm, $\|X\|^2=\operatorname{tr}(X^TX)$, which comes from the Frobeinus inner product $\langle X, Y \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(X^TY)$.  We can use bilinearity of this inner product to break things apart into pieces that are easier to manage.  We are trying to minimize

$$ \langle X,X \rangle-2 \langle X,Y \rangle + \langle Y,Y \rangle + \langle X,D^TDX \rangle.$$

There are various approaches one can take for the derivative of a function of matrices, but one nice approach is the gradient of $f(X)$ satisfies $f(X+h)=f(X)+\langle h,\nabla f(X) \rangle + O(h^2)$.  Using this, one can easily show that $\nabla \langle X,X \rangle=2X$, $\nabla \langle X,Y \rangle=Y$, and $\nabla \langle X,AX \rangle=(A+A^T)X.$

Thus, the gradient of the full expression is $2(X-Y)+2D^TDX$.  Setting this equal to $0$ yields

$$ X = (I+D^TD)^{-1}Y.$$

Comment: Thank you for your time.